# g++ 10.2 shows cpp version 14

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64

I am beginner in cpp.

I had a old cpp which version i dont know. I ran the following to check the version.

```
int main()
{
    if (__cplusplus == 201703L)
        std::cout << "C++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L)
        std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L)
        std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L)
        std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else
        std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
c++14
```

After this, i tried to upgrade c++ version to latest c++ 20. Which i learned that each compilers support all different parts of c++. I downloaded `mingw64 10.2` and added `PATH` variables.

If i run `g++ --version`, it correctly shows `g++ version`. However above code still prints that i am using `c++14`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `g++ -std=c++20` to compile the file

Comment: @ThomasSablik Works. Would you post this as an answer please? If answer already exist raise a flag. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Usually, the default C++ version is C++14 on most compilers, if you want another version, you need to enable it as @ThomasSablik said.

Comment: @therealcain _"Usually, the default C++ version is C++14 on most compilers"_ No, it depends on your gcc version, e.g. the packaged CentOS or RHEL gcc has C++11 as default version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the C++ standard in `gcc` with the command line argument `-std`. Some of the supported standards are `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17`, `-std=c++20`.